# Why do I get this error - 1622767296: Socket error on client clientId, disconnecting.?

Tags: reactjs, mqtt, ws

So I have a react.js app which subscribes to `ws://localhost:9001` so it can connect to a mqtt broker which I run on docker. Usually, I have a java app which sends some data to the react.js app via mqtt and that all worked until like a week ago. I opened it today and it does not work anymore.

Instead of the java app, I am using MQTT.fx to publish data but the react.js receives nothing and also it shows no exception and all I get is this from the docker mqtt broker image:

```
  2766869: mosquitto version 1.4.12 (build date 2017-06-01 13:03:46+0000) starting

1622766869: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.

1622766869: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.

1622766869: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.

1622766869: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9001.

1622766870: New client connected from 172.19.0.1 as clientId (c1, k60).

1622766874: Socket error on client clientId, disconnecting.

1622766875: New client connected from 172.19.0.1 as clientId (c1, k60).

1622767296: Client clientId has exceeded timeout, disconnecting.

1622767296: Socket error on client clientId, disconnectin
```

EDIT:
So I output `all` in the `log_type` and I receive this:

> `1622804209: Sending SUBACK to front_end_app
>
> 1622804209: Received SUBSCRIBE from front_end_app
>
> 1622804209: dd/switches (QoS 0)
>
> 1622804209: front_end_app 0 acs/switches
>
> 1622804209: Sending SUBACK to front_end_app
>
> 1622804209: Received SUBSCRIBE from front_end_app
>
> 1622804209: dd/mode (QoS 0)
>
> 1622804209: front_end_app 0 dd/mode
>
> 1622804209: Sending SUBACK to front_end_app
>
> 1622804209: Received SUBSCRIBE from front_end_app
>
> 1622804209: dd/port (QoS 0)
>
> 1622804209: front_end_app 0 dd/port
>
> 1622804209: Sending SUBACK to front_end_app
>
> 1622804209: Received SUBSCRIBE from front_end_app`

EDIT 2:

I just checked and I am actually able to publish from the react.js app but can't receive

[image]

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64125854/11810946) help? I'd guess the issue is in the app; if you set `log_type` to `all` in [`mosquitto.conf](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) you will get more info on what is happening (or, perhaps, not happening in this case). Note that Mosquitto 1.4.12 is pretty old now so worth considering upgrading.

Comment: @Brits Hey, thanks for the advise. I updated it to 1.6.9 and also changed the `log_type` to `all` but it doesnt really show me much

Comment: That was kind of expected (as it looks like the connection is timing out I guessed there was no traffic; but there do appear to be pings coming through regularly). All of your logs show the client connection (`front_end_app` or `mqttjs_xxxxx`) but no connections, or publish messages, from another connection. You mention you are publishing using `MQTT.fx` but this does not seem to be in the logs.

Comment: @Brits and this is the issue, nothing is received

Comment: the broker will only relay messages that it receives and the logs only show incoming PUBLISH packets from `mqttjs_xxxxx`/`front_end_app` (which I assume are both your front end app) so I'm not seeing the messages you say you are sending from MQTT.fx (or even evidence that MQTT.fx has connected to the broker). Please check that the client id you are using in MQTT_fx is showing up in the logs (if not I'd guess you are connecting to a different broker) and update your question with those log lines.